# Link JavaScript project with Java project in Eclipse

Tags: java, javascript, eclipse, project

I want to link a Java project with a JavaScript project that I have in my Eclipse.

Basically, the Java project has a set of libraries that we are implementing on the JavaScript project, so, just to do not duplicate code, I want to link them.

How is it possible to do that?

This is the actual structure:

```
JSProj
  JSLib1
  JSLib2
  JSLib3

JavaProj
  App
    scripts
       (Here should be a link to JSProj)
```

Thanks for the hand!

Answer (score 4):

One way to accomplish this is to create a linked folder that points to the location of your JavaScript project.

`New > Folder > Advanced > Link to Alternate Location`

Then browse to the location of JSProj.

The downside is that this is a filesystem link, rather than a link within the workspace. Theoretically you would just want to add the JavaScript project to the Java project's build path, but it looks like that only works when they're both Java projects (or maybe just the same type).