# importing a javascript project in eclipse

Tags: javascript, eclipse

I was wondering if it was possible to separate my javascript libraries in different eclipse project and then import them in another dynamic web project like I would normally do for regular java sub-projects ?

This answer : [Link JavaScript project with Java project in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9085880/link-javascript-project-with-java-project-in-eclipse)
is what I want to do however I dont really like the answer ... I'd rather link to workspace projects rather than directly rely on the FileSystem .

It seems the JSDT ( http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/jsdt/ ) "adds a JavaScript project type and perspective to the Eclipse Workbench" but how do you use / import / link these JS projects in your java project ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Add it to the JavaScript Include Path of your web project from the relevant Property Page:

[image: JavaScript/Include Path property page for the project 'JS']

Comment: thank you for your help. I had hoped this would work for me but unfortunately, the JS project does not get included at deployment time == the js files are not copied to the deployment folder when testing my webapp on tomcat from eclipse for example ... I also tried to add the JS project to my Java project in deployment assembly but its not there ... so the js files are never copied to the target server directory. Any other idea ?

Comment: I had hoped this would work but the JS project never gets deployed to the target Tomcat server.woops ... double post

Comment: No, deployment as a web app only pulls in other projects as .jars into the WEB-INF/lib folder.  If you want JS in your web app, it needs to be in the WebContent folder itself (or another defined root) to be sent to the browser.