# How to develop a Durandal SPA with Java backend in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, durandal

I already have some sort of a prototype of Durandal app, but now I need to add functionality to it which requires backend. I am told to go with Java, but then how do I import the Durandal app into Eclipse? Eclipse and durandal have their own project structures and they're everything but the same... Is trying to move the whole thing into Eclipse even a good idea? If no, what are the alternatives?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13558610/importing-a-javascript-project-in-eclipse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you don't need to have a single project for both the Java back-end and the Durandal front-end. You could have 2 different projects (and use Eclipse of the back-end, with  whatever editor/ide you are already using for the front-end.

You can use Eclipse for both (I personally do). There's two approaches I've used:

(a) Have two separate projects.

In this case one project would be a Java project and the other the Durandal project. The Durandal project could be a "Static Web" project (if you have web tools plugins installed) where you copy all Durandal files into the "WebContent" folder, or it could be a simple project. Since you won't be building from within Eclipse, it doesn't really matter.

(b) Have a common project.

In this case you would create a Java project, then inside it use New->Folder to create a folder for your Durandal content (e.g. webclient) and copy all your Durandal stuff in there.

As long as you have the Web Developer Tools plugins installed, you will be able to used the HTML/Javascript editors of Eclipse, regardless of which approach is used.